# How to upload wide (15,000 + columns) CSV to Apache Hbase instance

Tags: python, apache, hbase, happybase

I have a CSV file representing a large matrix that I wish to upload to an Apache Hbase instance (running on AWS EMR, but that shouldn't matter). The CSV contains ~15000 columns and ~50000 rows. The matrix's cell values are integers.

The CSV looks something like this:

```
ROW_KEY col1 col2 col3 .... col15000
row1 0    1  125  456
row2 23   23  45  ...
row3 ...  ...  ...
...
row50000
```

I'm planning on keeping my HBase schema in a single column family, with each of the columns (col1, col2, etc) as column qualifiers.

I've looked into iterating over the CSV in a python script and uploading each row using something like [happybase](https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but that seems to take quite a while.

I've looked into the [ImportTSV](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/ImportTsv.html) tool, but it looks like the tool requires an argument to detail all the column names, such as this:

```
Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:name,cf2:exp
```

Detailing tens of thousands of columns in the args doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: The same way you would upload csv with 5 columns: parse csv line by line, use HBase client api and create Put for each row

Comment: I was hoping to do a single submit of a CSV - doing a put for each row when the row has 15000 columns can be painfully slow.

Comment: You can group puts in batches. Single put is not the best option.

Comment: `put(Put put)` batches in the background, so you don't have to worry about batching it yourself. `hbase.client.write.buffer` is the setting you'll be most interested in.